# Populating an object property with one of a limited set of characters using AutoFixture

Tags: c#, autofixture

I am using AutoFixture to generate a list of ProblemClass objects to be used for testing.  ProblemClass is defined as

```
public class ProblemClass
{
    int Id {get; set;}
    string ProblemField {get; set;}
}
```

ProblemField can contain one of 3 values "A", "B" or "C".  I can't change ProblemClass so I can't make ProblemField an enum.

How can I get AutoFixture to populate the ProblemField property of each object in my list randomly with an "A", "B", or "C"?

(e.g. `myList[0].ProblemField` is "A", `myList[1].ProblemField` is "C", etc.)

Thanks!

Comment: You have no access modifier on the ProblemField property, but I guess that it's actually public?

Comment: Is that `ProblemClass` definition accurate?

Comment: Sorry, the properties are both public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customize how the ProblemClass is generated.

This should work:

```cs
fixture
    .Customize<ProblemClass>(ob =>
        ob
            .With(
                x => x.ProblemField,
                (int i) => "ABC".Substring(i % 3, 1)));
```

More info:

[From the cheatsheet](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/wiki/Cheat-Sheet#customize-type)

[Marks blog](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2009/09/22/CustomizingAType'sBuilderWithAutoFixture/)

Answer (score -1):

Would something like this work for you?

```
public class ProblemClass
{
    static Random r = new Random();
    const string options = "ABC";

    public ProblemClass(int id)
    {
        Id = id;
        ProblemField = options[r.Next(options.Length)].ToString();
    }

    public int Id { get; }
    public string ProblemField { get; }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change the ProblemClass class.  It stays as is, and I need to create instances of it with AutoFixture.